# How do I find all records of a model where the association has a count equal to 0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models - `Question` and `Answer`.

I would like to find the number of questions that have 0 answers.

So I tried stuff like this, that didn't work:

```
Question.where("answers.count = 0").count

Question.where("answers.count", 0).count

Question.joins(:answers).where("answers.count == 0").count
```

and a few other permutations.

How do I get what I want?

Answer (score 4):

While Edward's answer works, you can and should do this with pure sql:

```
Question.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN answers.id ON answers.question_id = questions.id').group("questions.id").having("count('answers.id') = 0")
```

However, if you just want the total count of questions without answers, I don't think you can do that with ActiveRecord methods. You will need to build the sql statement yourself.

```
Question.find_by_sql(
   "select count(id) as total from (
       select questions.*, count(answers.id) from questions 
       left outer join answers on answers.question_id = questions.id 
       group by questions.id having count(answers.id) = 0) 
    as noanswers").first.total
```

Comment: But if you just do joins(:answers), it's an inner join and so won't have questions that don't have an answer!

Comment: Question.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN answers.id ON answers.question_id = question.id').group("questions.id").having("count('answers.id') = 0")

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives me the following error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  schema "answers" does not exist`.

Comment: However, what does work, is this query: `Question.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN answers.id ON answers.question_id = question.id').group("questions.id").having("count('answers.id') = 0")`. However, that outputs an entire collection/array of all the results. All I want is an integer count value. When I add `.count` to the end of that, it throws another error. Any ideas on how I may get a count using this query?

Comment: There must be a simpler way to achieve this though.

Comment: I can't prove a negative. Until someone proves otherwise, there's not a simpler way - not with pure sql anyway

Comment: Is this still the best way?  Or has activerecord been updated to accommodate this with rails 5?

Answer (score 3):

```
Question.select('questions.*, COUNT(questions.id) AS question_count').joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN questions ON questions.answer_id = answers.id').group('answers.id').select { |a| a.question_count == 0}.count
```

will get what you want.  But it is a bit of a nightmare - I wonder if I'm missing something?

If you want to do lots of complicated queries, then squeel is worth looking at - https://github.com/ernie/squeel

Or if you just want to count the number of answers then you could use a counter_cache http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Here's a blog post about how to add a counter cache http://blog.obiefernandez.com/content/2011/08/adding-a-counter-cache-to-existing-records.html

Edit
Thanks to @boulder for pointing to the pure sql answer

```
Question.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN answers ON answers.question_id = questions.id').group('questions.id').having("count('answers.id') = 0").count
```

Comment: I just want to do this on the command-line. Seems a bit....overkill. There MUST be a simpler way to do this...no?

Comment: Yes - I feel that too, but I can't think of one.

Comment: A counter cache, once you've set it up, is very straight forward and does exactly what you want.

Comment: I have heard about counter cache a few times, but never really looked into it. You may be right. But once I have a counter_cache column, then what would I do? Something like: `Question.where(:answer_count => 0)` or something like that?

Comment: Btw, when I ran this query, I got this error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  table name "questions" specified more than once`

Comment: Yes to your how to use the counter cache question

Comment: When I ran the updated query with the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, I get this error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  schema "answers" does not exist`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26780/discussion-between-edward-and-marcamillion)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just doing it on the command line and don't care about performance, then I'd just do Question.all.map(&:id) - Answer.all.map(&:question_id).uniq to get all the question ids.  Basically, you're selecting all the questions, finding their question ids, and subtracting that set from the set of all question ids.  What's left is the questions with no answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Question.find_by_sql('select * from questions where (select count(*) from answers where question_id = question.id) = 0').count
```